# PHP логическая путаница.Как читать файл в несколько строк. Как записать файл в одну строку?

Tags: php, циклы, отладка, логика

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить.
Нужно записывать данные в 1 строку с инпутов (записывает в 2 строки, а поначалу вообще копировал весь файл(а) + новые данные(б) и дозаписывал = (ааб). И нужно, что бы он мог читать если несколько строк в файле. По логике так то он и должен делать, но почему-то если в файле запись на 2й + строке, то он не находит 1й и 2й индекс. Как исправить код, что бы он записывал данные в 1 строку, и что бы на всякий случай читал с 2+ строк?
P.S: Дебагером все еще не научился пользоваться (

Для удобства чтения - добавил для вас еще скрин с IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Write inputs

```
<?php
$name3=null;
$surname3=null;
$age=null;
  if(isset($_POST['name3'],$_POST['surname3'],$_POST['age3'])){
    $file=("table.txt");
    // $curent=file_get_contents($file);//make copy file - need off!
    $curent=";".$_POST['name3']."_";
    $curent.=$_POST['surname3']."_";
    $curent.=$_POST['age3'];
    file_put_contents($file,$curent,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);}
    // file_put_contents($file,$curent,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);}
    // _______
    // read data from table.txt
?>
```

Read table.txt

```
<?php
  $string1=file("table.txt");
  for($i=0;$i<count($string1);$i++){//why did not working if 2+ strings?
    $datatxt=explode(";", $string1[$i]);
      for($j=0;$j<count($datatxt);$j++){
        $mass=explode("_",$datatxt[$j]);
        $name="<tr align='center'><td>".$mass[0]."</td>";
        $surname="<td>".$mass[1]."</td>";
        $age="<td>".$mass[2]."</td></th>";
        echo $name.$surname.$age;}}
?>
```

---

table.txt

```
Angela_First_16;Lily_Oto_18;Ann_Girl_31
```

Answer (score 2):

этот код

```
for($i=0;$i<count($string1);$i++){
$datatxt=explode(";", $string1[$i]);
```

нада заменить на

```
$datatxt = explode(";", $string1);
for($i=0; $i < count($datatxt); $i++){
```

Comment: Наконец-то)
Спасибо вам большое @Lesyuk Alexey!))
подскажите еще пожалуйста, что еще нужно исправить (ошибка: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given) - ему не нравится, что $string1 - строка?

Comment: P.S: если написать implode или поставить [0] индекс, то он все значения из файла выводит х3 раза.

Comment: И может подскажите еще как в одну строку записывать, вместо записи с новой строки?)
explode не нравится, что там массив а не строка?!

Comment: ему не нравится то что точка запятой в начале конактинируется с  $curent а должнабыть в конце, чтобы в одну строку уберите из кода <tr> , <th>

Comment: так ведь <tr>,<th> это уже он когда читает с файла (а желательно бы еще, что бы он записывал в файл в одну строку).
А точка с запятой в начале, это из логики программы (точно не помню, что именно но ему что-то не нравилось когда в файле последний символ ";") по этому, я поставил ее в начало. =)
Вообщем программа уже работает, сейчас поставил перед собой задачу - написать парсер сайтов.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Заработал код!
    Что бы читал несколько строк в 1 массив написал вместо file - file_get_contents 
    с нужным индексом. В одну строку так и не разобрался как записать, но и так работает))
    Пора начинать выполнять следующую задачу на пути изучения php!)
```

*Спасибо @Lesyuk Alexey, за ответ!*